# Apple Mach-O Linker error with Allegro5 and Xcode with CMake

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I'm trying to set up a project project in Xcode with allegro. I installed allegro5 using homebrew. My CMakeLists.txt is as below:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES "main.cpp")
add_executable(core ${SOURCE_FILES})

if(WIN32)
    # TODO.
else(APPLE)
    set(ALLEGRO_INCLUDE "/usr/local/include")
    set(ALLEGRO_LIB "/usr/local/lib")
    set(ALLEGRO_DYLIB, "/usr/local/lib/*.dylib")
    set(ALLEGRO_LINK_FLAGS "-lallegro -lallegro_main")
endif()

include_directories(${ALLEGRO_INCLUDE})
link_directories(${ALLEGRO_LIB})
file(GLOB LIBRARIES ${ALLEGRO_DYLIB})

target_link_libraries(core ${LIBRARIES} ${ALLEGRO_LINK_FLAGS})
```

However, I keep getting the error: `ld: library not found for -lallegro`

EDIT:

Edited CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES "main.cpp")
add_executable(core ${SOURCE_FILES})

if(WIN32)
    # TODO.
else(APPLE)
    set(ALLEGRO_INCLUDE "/usr/local/include")
    set(ALLEGRO_LIB "/usr/local/lib")
    set(ALLEGRO_DYLIB, "/usr/local/lib/*.dylib")
endif()

include_directories(${ALLEGRO_INCLUDE})
link_directories(${ALLEGRO_LIB})
file(GLOB LIBRARIES ${ALLEGRO_DYLIB})

target_link_libraries(core ${LIBRARIES} ${ALLEGRO_DYLIB})
```

And now I'm getting the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
     (maybe you meant: __al_mangled_main)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Misprint in `set(ALLEGRO_DYLIB, ...) ` - remove a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood `target_link_libraries`, you don't set the link flags here, but you indicate the list of libraries you want to target, so that would be:

```
target_link_libraries(core ${LIBRARIES} ${ALLEGRO_DYLIB})
```

Otherwise you will get flags like `-l-lallegro`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed it to that but now I get the error `implicit entry/start for main executable`. According to [this](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=FAQ#Why_do_I_get_undefined_symbol_errors.3F), I need to set linker flags.

Comment: No, the documentation is badly written, you need to link against the `allegro_main` library.

Comment: I updated the file according to your advice and updated the question. I'm still getting the error. Can you see if I'm doing it correctly please?

Comment: Well, where is your `main`?

Comment: `main` is in a file called main.cpp right next to the CMakeLists.txt in the root folder. Then the XCode project is in a folder called `build`. So the structure is root has three itemsL CmakeLists.txt, main.cpp and a folder called build. Then inside build is where I do `cmake -G Xcode ..`.

Comment: With the information you gave us, that's about what I can say. You are not showing your main file, you haven't provided the generated link command, you haven't shown that `allegro_main` is really linked in, etc.